# Desire2Learn Valence API Start Time UTC Format?

Tags: desire2learn

What is the correct format for entering a start date and end date for a course with the valence api?

I've tried standard UTC date and time with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out from this page:

[UTCDatetime Link](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/conventions.html#term-utcdatetime)

I had forgotten the quotation marks!!! I guess it must be friday :)